# How can I calculate the density of air?

Tags: chemical-engineering, unit

I major in chemical engineering, and I'm solving a example of unit operations.
The textbook is Warren L. McCabe, Unit Operations of Chemical Engineering 7th ed.
Here is example 24.1.
[image]

And this is its solution.

[image]

From this, it says that the density of air is 29/369 × 492/620.
But it omitted the untis, so I can't understand the equation.
I assume that this equation is probably ρ = PM/RT, since molecular weight of air is 28.97 g/mol when I searched for it.
But the numbers 369, 492, 620 are still mystery. What is those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at Text equation 1.29, the 492/620 is Temperature in Rankine.

$$T°F = T°R - 459.67$$

Ice point is 491.67°R.  160°F = 619.67°R.

If you do the math, it does not equal 0.0641, because the 369 is wrong.  The math to get 0.0641 means 369 should be 359.

1 lb-mole of an ideal gas at 0°C and 1 atm occupies 359 $ft^3$ absolute.

The molecular weight of air is 29 lb/lb-mole.

$$\frac {29 lb/lb-mole}{359 ft^3/lb-mole} \times \frac {492°R}{160°F + 460°R} = 0.0461 lb/ft^3$$